How to change the playback speed of a video in media9?
I use following code to include a video in a beamer slide. However, it seems that 3Dplayspeed does not modify the playing speed. What is wrong?
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
  label=some_dice,
  width=5cm, height=5cm,
  addresource=video1.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  passcontext,
  flashvars={
    source=video1.mp4
   &loop=true
  },
  3Dplayspeed=100
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


According to the manual, the option 3Dplayspeed applies to 3D files and not to an mp4 file thus it does not modify the playing speed in the example in the question.
